# ggplot2 legend and axes not resizing when using knitr

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I am attempting to put two ggplots next to each other in a knitr document. I am able to get them next to each other, by using the chunk options that are shown online. However when I do this the legend and axes labels are not being resized. They are being cut off and are much bigger than the plot. I am sure there is something that I am missing, but I don't know what it is.

Here is a minimal example that produces the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<data, echo=FALSE>>=
library(ggplot2)
School<-c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b")
Name<-c("Tom", "Jim", "Sam", "Smith", "Bill", "John", "Kim", "Jill", "Rob", "Son", "Moon", "Star")
ave1<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
ave2<-c(12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
table1<-data.frame(School, Name, ave1, ave2)
@

<<graphs, fig.width=3, fig.height=3, out.width='.49\\linewidth', echo=FALSE, fig.show='hold'>>=
ggplot(table1, aes(x=School, y=ave1, fill=Name))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_grey()+
  ylab("Average 1 Scores")+
  xlab("a vs. b Schools")+
  ggtitle("Means for a and b Schools on average 1")

ggplot(table1, aes(x=School, y=ave2, fill=Name))+
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity")+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_grey()+
  ylab("Average 2 Scores")+
  xlab("a vs. b Schools")+
  ggtitle("Means for a and b Schools on average 2")
@



\end{document}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: does increasing `fig.width` help?

Comment: @baptise that works for me.  I think the OP is trying to constraint he dimensions too much.